# Failover server for SQL Server mirror errors after reboot

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, replication, mirroring

I have two Windows Server 2008 servers set up, both running SQL Server 2008 R2. One is used as a primary DB, the other as a mirror failover (two website DBs + ASPState for sessions). Everything works great until one of the DBs becomes the primary after the server that it runs on has been rebooted. I get this error:

`Invalid object name 'tempdb.dbo.ASPStateTempSessions'.`

I am able to solve this by running the stored procedure `ASPState_Startup` (which executes `ASPState.dbo.CreateTempTables`), but only if the DB is the "principal" state. When a server has rebooted, it will always come back up with the DBs in a "Mirror / Restoring" state, meaning I cannot run that SP at startup.

Any suggestions on how I can get around this issue?

Comment: It would seem to me that there is something wrong with the mirroring.  Rather than putting on a a workaround, have you asked why you are getting the error in the first place?  Try http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Mirroring is functioning okay; this is by design because tempdb is not and can not be mirrored.  Can't hurt to get it over to dba.se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting up a SQL Agent job that runs on each instance, every minute, and executes a script to look for the database in a not restoring state, check for the table and then execute the procedure if it doesn't exist.  I took the object names from your question so it may need to be changed if they are off from your environment.

```
if exists ( select 1 from sys.databases where state_desc <> 'RESTORING' and 
[name] = 'ASPState' )
begin
    if ( object_id('tempdb.dbo.ASPStateTempSessions') is null )
    begin
        exec sp_executesql @stmt = N'exec ASPState.dbo.CreateTempTables'
    end
end
```

Comment: This did the trick - just one minor issue with the code. ```'exec ASPState.dbo.CreateTempTables'``` should be ```N'exec ASPState.dbo.CreateTempTables'```. Thanks!

Comment: changed the answer to reflect your feedback.